# How can i use custom icon in ng-map marker(angular)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

I have list of shops which contains latitude and longitude and  i have particuler user latitude and longitude.

when user clicks map button two marker is showing in map which is identify user and shop location

how can i change  that two marker icons instead of default marker A and B how can i use my own custom icons for marker
1.http://www.clker.com/cliparts/U/M/C/p/x/C/google-maps-pin-green.svg

2.http://www.clker.com/cliparts/q/I/Q/u/Z/1/marker-hi.png

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMap'])
    .controller("myCntrl", function ($scope) {
      var _lat1 =12.904778 ;
     var _lon1 =77.585680;
     $scope.lat = _lat1;
     $scope.lon = _lon1;
      $scope.positions = [{pos:[$scope.lat, $scope.lon],name:"User"}];
      $scope.center = [$scope.lat, $scope.lon];
      
      
      $scope.viewMap = false;
      $scope.updateMap = function(dealer) {
        $scope.lat1 = dealer.S_Latitude;
       $scope.lon1 = dealer.S_Longitude;
       icon : 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/q/I/Q/u/Z/1/marker-hi.png',
        $scope.positions = [{pos:[$scope.lat, $scope.lon],name:"User"}, {pos:[dealer.S_Latitude, dealer.S_Longitude],name:"Store"}];
        $scope.viewMap = true;
        $scope.path = [[$scope.lat, $scope.lon], [dealer.S_Latitude, dealer.S_Longitude]];
      }
    
    $scope.dealers = [{
        
        S_Email_id: "aditiya@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "samsung",
        Store_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,Software Faults,Hardware Faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
  S_Latitude: "12.93489905",
  S_Longitude: "77.57070772",
  S_clocation: ""
    }, {
       
        S_Email_id: "rajs@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia",
        Store_Name: "sri shakthi mobile service",
        S_Services: "Settings Faults,Regular Service,Hardware Faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles",
  S_Latitude: "12.9599264",
  S_Longitude: "77.5924983",
  S_clocation: ""
    }, {
        
        S_Email_id: "sprtive23@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia,samsung",
        Store_Name: "sun mobile service center",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,overall maintenance,Mobile Shield Installation",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
  S_Latitude: "12.911229",
  S_Longitude: "77.519281",
  S_clocation:""
  },
 {
        
        S_Email_id: "super@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia,samsung",
        Store_Name: "ragu mobile service center",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,overall maintenance,Mobile Shield Installation",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
  S_Latitude: "12.909999",
  S_Longitude: "77.506871",
  S_clocation: ""
  }
    ]

 
  
  

 }
)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>

<style>
    

    .custom-marker {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: #7F7F7F solid 1px;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .custom-marker:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 7px 6px 0;
    border-color: #fff transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: -6px;
    bottom: -6px;
    left: 50%;
    }
    .custom-marker:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 7px 6px 0;
    border-color: #7F7F7F transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-left: -6px;
    bottom: -7px;
    left: 50%;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myCntrl">
      <label>Case sensitive Search on Label</label><br>
      <input ng-model="query" type="text" placeholder="Search for name" />
      <div>
        <ng-map zoom="12" center="{{lat}}, {{lon}}">
          
          <directions
          draggable="true"
          panel="directions-panel"
          travel-mode="DRIVING"
          origin="{{lat}}, {{lon}}"
          destination="{{lat1}}, {{lon1}}">
        </directions>
        
          
        </ng-map>
        <br><br><br>
      </div>
      <div>
      <div ng-repeat="dealer in dealers">
        {{dealer.Store_Name}}<br>
    {{dealer.S_Email_id}}<br>
    {{dealer.S_clocation}}
        
        <input type="button" name="map" id="map" value="map" ng-click="updateMap(dealer);"><br><br>
   </div>
   </div>
   <br><br><br>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/6ZY5YdaR5qrdw41jpO2t?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the custom-marker directive. It will kill your performance for any large number of markers (e.g. 200+). Instead use the 'icon' attribute of the standard marker, something like this:

```
<marker id="L: {{loc.position[0]}}, {{loc.position[1]}}" position="{{loc.position}}" icon="{ url:'/assets/images/deal-indicator.png', scaledSize:[32,40], origin: [0,0], anchor: [16,40] }">
```

The marker directive is just a wrapper for the Google Maps API v3 standard 'marker', so all of the standard marker properties are accessible when using ng-map.

The icon is a Javascript object, and the properties are as follows (from the documentation):

> **Properties**
>
> anchor | Type: Point
>
> The position at which to anchor an image in correspondence to the
>   location of the marker on the map. By default, the anchor is located
>   along the center point of the bottom of the image.
>
> origin | Type: Point
>
> The position of the image within a sprite, if any. By default, the
>   origin is located at the top left corner of the image (0, 0).

The icon can also be set programatically by using the 'setIcon' method of the marker, e.g.:

```
myMarker.setIcon('/assets/images/deal-indicator-selected.png');
```

Or, construct an icon object first and set this as the marker:

```
var customIcon = {
    url: "/images/my-marker.png",
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(32, 40),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), 
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 40)
};

myMarker.setIcon(customIcon);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, please, read the documentation about custom markers for `ng-maps`: 
https://ngmap.github.io/#/!custom-marker.html

```
<custom-marker id="usa" position="united state of america" on-click="ifNeeded()"></custom-marker>
```

Edit: Full code below;

```
<ng-map zoom="12" center="{{lat}}, {{lon}}">

      <directions
      draggable="true"
      panel="directions-panel"
      travel-mode="DRIVING"
      origin="{{lat}}, {{lon}}"
      destination="{{lat1}}, {{lon1}}">
    </directions>

    <custom-marker id="can" position="canada" on-click="click()">
        <div>
            <b>Hi, USA</b>
            <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/2014-world-cup-flags/32/USA-icon.png" />
        </div>
    </custom-marker>

</ng-map>
```

Comment: i am new to angular please help me out .if you don't mind please update my code

Comment: I have provided you with the answer, I will not write your code for you, that is not what StackOverflow is for.

Comment: Acutally i don't know where i have to add that code . i am struggling that's why i asked sorry

Comment: no my expectaton . when user click map button two marker icon  is showing now .instead of that two marker icon how can we show two different marker custom marker icons in map

Comment: nothing is working can you please check .http://plnkr.co/edit/6ZY5YdaR5qrdw41jpO2t?p=preview